# Storing JSON payload as Files based on unit of work pattern

Tags: files, fflib

I have been trying to store a huge JSON Payload(received as a response from external Integration) as a salesforce File and attach it to the Object's(called as EventLog) record.But my org is based on FFLib Apex commons and quite frankly I am pretty new to this.So how do I use unit of work pattern to insert the Content document and later link it to my Object's record.
Consider me a novice and any immediate help is very much appreciated.
This is what I am wrongly trying:

````
        X_EventLog__c sObj = new X_EventLog__c();
        sObj.X_ScheduleTime__c = manualRequest.sendMessageTime;
        String payloadStr = JSON.serialize(manualRequest);
        createFileFromStringAttachedToRecord(payloadStr);
        uow.registerNew(sObj);

----------
       String payloadStr = JSON.serialize(manualRequest);
       Blob fileContents = Blob.valueOf(payloadStr);
        createFileAttachedToRecord(
            fileContents,
            EventLogJSON
        );
       public static void createFileAttachedToRecord(
        Blob fileContents,
        String fileName
    ) {
        ContentVersion fileToUpload = new ContentVersion();
        // S = Salesforce. The other options are: 'E' (external)
        // and 'L' (social customer service)
        fileToUpload.ContentLocation = 'S';
        fileToUpload.pathOnClient = fileName;
        fileToUpload.title = fileName;
        fileToUpload.versionData = fileContents;

        //I am confused here

        fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork uow = X_Application.UnitOfWork.newInstance();
        uow.commitWork();
    }```
````

Answer (score 0):

ContentVersion and ContentDocumentLink are a bit tricky because you need to commit the `ContentVersion` in order to get the `ContentDocumentId` which is used in the junction object `ContentDocumentLink`.  The basic pattern is as follows

```
public void myMethod() {
     fflib_ISObjectUnitOfWork uow = Application.UnitOfWork.newInstance();
     ContentVersion cv = new ContentVersion (...);
     uow.RegisterNew(cv);
     uow.commitWork(); // ContentDocument will get created
     ContentVersion[] cvs = ContentVersionsSelector.newInstance.selectById(new Set<Id>{cv.Id});

     // now, start a new Unit of Work
     uow = Application.UnitOfWork.newInstance();
     uow.registerNew(new ContentDocumentLink(
          ContentDocumentId = cvs[0].ContentDocumentId,
          LinkedEntityId = myOtherObj.Id));
     uow.commitWork(); // ContentDocumentLink will get created
  }
```